# htaccess rewrite rule for image url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the url:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/i/1Q2GmFuFdZ.jpg`

I want to rewrite a rule that makes it go to the file `image.php?id=1Q2GmFuFdZ.jpg`

In my PHP file, I have this

```
<?PHP
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

This is what I have in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]+[a-z]{3})$ image.php?id=$1
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
Array ( [id] => image.php )
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm no regex pro but I know the basics.

Thanks

EDIT:
Forgot to add 0-9 in expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_rewrite rules are applied recursively. Here is what happens when you request `1Q2GmFuFdZ.jpg`:

- `1Q2GmFuFdZ.jpg` matches the pattern, becomes `image.php?id=1Q2GmFuFdZ.jpg`
- Since filename has changed, another iteration is performed with the re-written URL
- `image.php` ***matches the pattern as well*** and rewritten as `image.php?id=image.php`
- File name or directory did not change so no further iteration is performed
- End result: `image.php?id=image.php`

Solution: add this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule image\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{3})$ image.php?id=$1
```

The second rule acts as a hand-brake. You need to tweak rule #3 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your Rewrite rule is wrong. It should be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^i/(.+)$ /image.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I think it will still produce the same result (not verified though).